# XMLHttpRequest Not returning value - Status 202

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, web-services, xmlhttprequest

Currently I'm working on a project that using webservice (**using VB.Net and Javascript**), when I debug the code, the XmlHttpRequest.status return **202** . I compared to my previous webservice project, and I found that the XmlHttpRequest.status return **200**, and it works.

I've been googling about status **202** and here's the info and here's the [link](https://httpstatuses.com/202).

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
>   upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.

Anyone bother to help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whether a service returns `200` or `202` depends on how the service is designed.  Both mean success, but there is a distinction between the two in meaning: `200` means your request was processed and completed successfully; `202` means your request was successfully accepted for *later* processing, and the eventual outcome of that processing is unknown at the moment.  In other words, your request was added to a queue on the server.

If a web service is designed to give a `202` response for a particular API method, then in many cases it will also provide a separate method to check on the status of the original request.  You would need to consult the documentation for this particular web service (if there is any), or ask the service author (if you have a way to contact them), to find out if there is such a status method and how to call it.

As for how to handle a `202` response in code, treat it as a "tentative success".  As far as you know, everything is OK unless a later status check tells you otherwise.  If there is a method to check status, set a timer so that you can call that method later to find out what happened, and proceed from there as appropriate.  If there is no such method available, then there's not much else you can do but assume everything will be processed successfully and move on.

Comment: Hi @Brian, unfortunately, I'm the author for both Client and Host, the thing is the host always return 202 if I put it on "CORS" configuration, but it will return 200 if i put it on "NON-CORS" configuration. Because of that, the XMR response text always return nothing.